# An event for "this row was just loaded" in GWT cell framework

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have a list of ids of rows that should be selected, but not the actual objects that will be selected.  For example, I know Users 16 and 25 should be selected, but I don't have an instance representing them.  This could be because they're on a different page of data that I haven't loaded yet.

I want to be able to select these users programmatically even though their data is not loaded yet.  I'm implementing a function called `setSelectedIds()` and it's working great - I scan all visible objects, and if their id matches one of the ids in my set, I set it Selected.  Likewise, if the user changes a selection through the human interface, I catch the SelectionChangeEvent and determine whether an id should be added or removed to my backing list of ids.

### The actual question:

**Is there an event that's always fired when data has been loaded via `updateRowData()`?** The only thing missing from my implementation is a way to handle the loading of new data.  I need to be notified when new data is loaded, so I can decide whether to select it or not.  RangeChangeEvents happen to soon - those handlers are fired before the data is loaded, and selectionModel.getSelected() returns some null objects.  RowCountChangeEvents only happen when the total number of rows changes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you implement your own `SelectionModel`? When it's asked whether an object `isSelected`, it compares its ID with your list of selected IDs. You could even generalize it by using the object's key (given by the `ProvidesKey`) rather than an hard-coded `getId`.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better idea. Thanks!  For future readers: I actually ended up subclassing CellTable to provide the events I mentioned above, and it's working rather well, but the SelectionModel is a more logical place achieve the behavior I need. Next time!